# check if a cell of table is <th>

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have a table like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>TH</th>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I want to get the amount of columns in JS I can simply do something like

```
var columnCount = tableElement.tBodies[0].rows[0].cells.length
```

In this case the output is 4. Is there any way to find out how many `<th>` are inside a table row, so that the output for that example is 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var thCount = tableElement.tBodies[0].rows[0].getElementsByTagName('th').length
```

or if you want only td's:

```
var tdCount = tableElement.tBodies[0].rows[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length
```

Comment: You can omit the *tBodies* property unless you want a particular table section. If only the first is required, then `tableElement.rows[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length` is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
var columnCount = tableElement.tBodies[0].rows.length
```

This is to get *all* the rows.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to count the rows of a table. I want to count the table cells (column), but just the `<td>` without `<th>`

Comment: Yeah sorry I misunderstood your question. Check @Grief-Code's answer.

Comment: All the rows of the table would  be `table.rows.length`. The above will only get those in the first *tbody* element and not count those in other table sections or in header or footer setions.